# How to avoid pushing our project to their own repository via git

Tags: github, bitbucket

We want to restrict my developer to upload our own project to their own repository.

Comment: You can't. If you provide them access to the code, you can't control what they do with it.

Comment: Is there any option available at enterprise edition?. We want to avoid data leakage from our network to out side the world via git ?.

Comment: No. That is part of git's distributed nature. You can't enforce permissions on an arbitrary replicating system.

Comment: @fuero what is the best way to secure my project within the origanization? .2). And how can i restrict private login using his own id inside the organization? 3).Can i restrict his login if we use Oauth login method?

Comment: You're still not getting it. They can copy all that source code into a `.zip` file and email it somewhere, or upload it to Facebook, or any number of other ways. There's no iron-clad technological solution here; hire vetted people, take good care of them, and if they violate that trust, it's time to get a lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

`Git` is a *distributed* version control system. It's core concept is that you (as a developer) have a complete copy of the code on your system you may *synchronize* to several sources (aka remotes) to facilitate cooperation - or even send around patches via e-mail (as the Linux kernel devs do).

In the simplest case, this is another computer you connect to with SSH and has a so-called `bare` copy (consult the [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) on that).

Whatever git hosting solutions are available take care of:

- offering different access protocols (`HTTP(S)`, `GIT`)
- handling authorization and authentication
- other fancy things like issue tracking, kanban boards, whatever.

The point here is that permissions and users only exist on the *server* side. Once you have the repo or branch(es) cloned to your computer, no way to enforce permissions exists. And even if there were, good luck restricting the user from passing on a ZIP file of the cloned copy.

Your only recourse here is, as @ceejayoz put it:

> There's no iron-clad technological solution here; hire vetted people, take good care of them, and if they violate that trust, it's time to get a lawyer.